# Issue when converted Adapter code from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-adapter

I have converted Adapter code from java to kotlin using IDE and I have an issue with ListFiler class not getting called in Kotlin code.

I have mentioned bellow the java code and equivalent kotlin code

In java it goes from FIRST - SECOND - THIRD

In Koltin code FIRST - SECOND - AND THIRD IS NOT HIT IN DEBUG

Could you please suggest what I might be doing wrong here please

Thanks
R

In java bellow is the flow

```
//FIRST - THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED WHICH GETS TO SECOND

public void applyCurrentFilter(Filter.FilterListener listener) {
    getFilter().filter(null, listener);
}


//SECOND - THIS IS CALLED WHICH GETS TO THIRD
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new ListFilter();
}



private class ListFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    //****THIRD - GETS INSIDE THIS performFiltering METHOD
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<ServiceOrder> tempFilteredObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        if (currentOrderFilter.getServiceTypes().size() == 0 && !currentOrderFilter.isHideClaimed()) {
            tempFilteredObjects.addAll(originalObjects);
        }

        if (currentOrderFilter.getServiceTypes().size() > 0) {
            tempFilteredObjects = filterServiceTypeResults(currentOrderFilter, originalObjects);
        }

        if (currentOrderFilter.isHideClaimed()) {
            tempFilteredObjects = filterOutClaimedOrders(tempFilteredObjects, currentOrderFilter, originalObjects);
        }

        filterResults.values = tempFilteredObjects;
        filterResults.count  = tempFilteredObjects.size();

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            filteredObjects = (List<ServiceOrder>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            filteredObjects.clear();
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

In Kotlin

```
//FIRST - THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED WHICH GETS TO SECOND
fun applyCurrentFilter(listener: FilterListener?) {
    filter.filter(null, listener)
}

//SECOND - THIS IS CALLED WHICH DOES NOT GET TO THIRD
override fun getFilter(): Filter =
    ListFilter()



private inner class ListFilter : Filter() {
    override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults {
    //*****DOES NOT GET HERE
        val filterResults = FilterResults()
        var tempFilteredObjects = ArrayList<ServiceOrder>()
        if (currentOrderFilter.serviceTypes.size == 0 && !currentOrderFilter.isHideClaimed) {
            tempFilteredObjects.addAll(originalObjects)
        }
        if (currentOrderFilter.serviceTypes.size > 0) {
            tempFilteredObjects = filterServiceTypeResults(currentOrderFilter, originalObjects)
        }
        if (currentOrderFilter.isHideClaimed) {
            tempFilteredObjects = filterOutClaimedOrders(tempFilteredObjects,
                currentOrderFilter,
                originalObjects
            )
        }
        filterResults.values = tempFilteredObjects
        filterResults.count = tempFilteredObjects.size
        return filterResults
    }

    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            filteredObjects = (results.values as List<ServiceOrder>).toMutableList()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            filteredObjects.clear()
            notifyDataSetInvalidated()
        }
    }
}
```

Please share your suggestions

thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

constraint maybe null. try to change method params to below, maybe work

```
override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults
```